# Cannot access python shell from virtualenv and Django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm on Windows 10.

I tried to install [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to use websockets with Django but it doesn't work. I got the following error : 
**Failed building wheel for Twisted**

I have still not succeeded to install channels.

But now I have a new problem, I can no anymore access **Python shell** from my virtual environment that I use for Django.

```
(myproject) D:\Django\mysite>py manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels'
```

I have no idea to solve my problem ... Someone could bring me help ?

Comment: I think it duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937256/error-while-installing-django-channels-on-python-3-5-on-windows

Comment: Thank you @SergeyPugach, I'm going to try, but if it doesn't work I gonna rebuild a new environment

Comment: Wait, rebuilding will only fix the shell problem. It won't fix the installation trouble!

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 I still have the message error. I have removed the virtual environment, reinstall it but nothing change...

Comment: Did you also try to install channels again (is that problem happening after you tried to reinstall channels)? Because this seems to be broken. So my idea is that you will start with a clean virtual environment. But the installation of channels won't work out of the box. You can either use a other package or ask how to fix that particular package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found the problem. In the tutorial https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html it is said to put 'channels' in the INSTALLED_APPS list  of the settings.py file. As soon as, I removed it, my shell worked again. For the problem of channels installation, I have been able to 'manually' install Twisted and the Channels... But when I put again 'channels' in the INSTALLED_APPS list  of the settings.py file problems come back again : python shell doesn't work anymore and runserver same... I'm going to create a  question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you broke something when you tried to install *channels*. From the spares information I guess that easiest course of action is to simply use a new virtual environment. After all that is the point of a virtual environment, if it breaks you can just rebuild it.

Manually fixing the virtual environment usually (this is my personal experience) takes more time then just setting up a new one.
For your installation trouble we need more info and you should open a new question.

So just deactivate your current environment ([this might help](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/)), delete it and set up a new one.

Keep in mind that this will only bring the shell back and give you a "fresh start". Your installation problem will usually not disappear!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I think I'm going to follow your advice. Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to ask about your installation problem. Also please mark this question as answered if you made it work.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I used rmvirtualenv myenvironment and reinstall it. I reinstall Django too. Nothing change with the shell, it still displays the same message error.... Would you have an idea ?

Comment: Did you try to install channels again? Or is the shell broken before you try to install channels?

Answer (score 0):

Try install channels by using `pip install channels`
then run shell again